# ActionLink in jquery table

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

i am new to mvc and jquery,

i have created one table with jquery but i don't know how we add one actionlink in each row and also i need to call one function on the onclick event.

my code is given bellow

```
 function loadData(data) {

            var tab = $('<table class="myTable"></table>');
            var thead = $('<thead></thead>');
            thead.append('<th>Id</th><th></th>');
            thead.append('<th>Username</th>');



            tab.append(thead);
            $.each(data, function (i, val) {

                var trow = $('<tr></tr>');
                trow.append('<td>' + val.empID + '</td>');
                trow.append('<td>' +"" + '</td>');
                trow.append('<td>' + val.empName + '</td>');
                trow.append('<td>' + '@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = val.empID })' + '</td>');


                tab.append(trow);
            });
```

here i got one error

"val is not in the current context"

please anyone help me to add one actionlink with click event.

Comment: You cannot html helper actionlinks through jquery . You can add simple html anchor tags instead

Comment: @RajanGoswami: just give the code,, please

Comment: Razor code is parsed on the server before its sent to the view. `val` is a javascript variable which does not even exist at that point (its not in context)

Comment: @user2006703 A little effort would be appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by changing your code as below.

```
function loadData(data) {    
            var tab = $('<table class="myTable"></table>');
            var thead = $('<thead></thead>');
            thead.append('<th>Id</th><th></th>');
            thead.append('<th>Username</th>');    
            tab.append(thead);
            $.each(data, function (i, val) {

                var trow = $('<tr></tr>');
                trow.append('<td>' + val.empID + '</td>');
                trow.append('<td>' +"" + '</td>');
                trow.append('<td>' + val.empName + '</td>');
                trow.append('<td><a href="/ControllerName/ActionName/"'+val.empID+'"></a></td>');


                tab.append(trow);
            });
```

Try this and let me know, if you required anymore information.

Comment: thanks its working,,,, i need to add one more column having button on each row and i need to call one function(jquery) on clicking that button how can i achieve that thing

Comment: trow.append('<td><input type="button" value="ClickButton" onclick="yourqueryfunction(param);" /></td>'); .. try this.

Comment: @user2006703 Welcome, don't forget to up-vote useful comments and answers.

Comment: but am unable to call a function on  that button click

Answer (score 0):

**Below Code Work Perfectly and Bind Table dynamically with Control.**

```
function bindTable (data)
{
usersTable = $('<table><thead><tr>'
             + '<th style="width: 300px;">Col 1</th><th>Col 2</th><th>Col 3</th><th>Col 4</th><th>Col 5</th>'
             + '</tr></thead ></table>').attr({ class: ["dataTable row-border hover"].join(' '), id: "table", style: "border: 1px solid; background-color:#d2d2d2;" });
             var rows = new Number("10");
             var cols = new Number("4");
             var tr = [];
             if (data != null) {
              for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {                           
              var row = $("<tr></tr>").attr({ class: ["class1", "class2", "class3"].join(' ') }).appendTo(table);
              $("<td></td>").html(data[i].Col1).appendTo(row);
              $("<td></td>").html(data[i].Col2).appendTo(row);
              $("<td></td>").html(data[i].Col3).appendTo(row);
              $("<td></td>").html(data[i].Col4).appendTo(row);
              $("<td></td>").html($('<a href=/ControllerName/Action?ParamId='+data[i].Id+'>Action</a>')).appendTo(row);

              }
            }
           table.appendTo("#Div");
            $("#table").DataTable({
            "aoColumns": [null, null, null, null, { "bSortable": false }]
            });
}
```